# to prove his guilt VS proving his guilt

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

1. There's no concrete evidence to prove his guilt.
2. There's no concrete evidence proving his guilt.

I know the first example is fine. I doubt whether the second one is grammatical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use infinitives after certain nouns to give more information about nouns.
Example:

> Ken has got the ability to be a great detective.

> Pensy made a promise to write an article on detectives.

For the second one, "proving" is similar to "to prove", but it's far less common used.

This kind of grammatical phenomenon is called predicative. We used infintives and verbs with ing to illustrate the identity, nature, character, traits and state of the subject or the object. To use "to do" or "doing" depends. For instance, we prefer "to do" than "doing" after "sb's job/dream/ambition etc".